# ¿Cómo conecto una base de datos sql server a un proyecto en C#, para que me funcione para todas las computadoras?

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con este tipo de proyectos, puedo crear un proyecto pero al momento de correr mi programa en otra computadora me marca error, debido a la cadena de conexión *(Bueno no entiendo mucho el tema)*.

¿Cómo son los pasos para que no me genere este tipo de errores?

Comment: Hola... podes ser mas especifico con este tipo de error, y especificar a que tipo de Sql server te estas conectando? es muy problable, que cuando cambies de maquina tengas que rearmar la cadena, inclusive preguntandole al usuario a que base conectarse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te tengo un buen [link (En ingles)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) que podría ayudarte a lo que necesitas, como sugerencia te digo que pruebes [SQL Server CE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx), pero para lo que buscas, sería bueno un dynamic attach o lo que Leandro sugiere en su respuesta.

Aunque aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo con SQL Server CE ([Link a la pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345910/5622844)):

Primero que nada, instala SQL Server CE (Si no lo tienes instalado), luego sigue estos pasos y prueba tu aplicación:

1. Crea un nuevo proyecto.
2. Agrega una referencia a `System.Data.SqlServerCe` (en `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` en mi pc)
3. Click derecho al proyecto en el explorador de soluciones, selecciona "Añadir => Nuevo elemento...", escoge "Base de datos Local" y llamala como desees, ejemplo MyDB.
4. Se va a crear un nuevo archivo *(MyDB.sdf)* dentro del proyecto (Una DB de SQL Server CE)
5. Click derecho a la base de datos y abrela, se abrirá la base de datos en el "Server Explorer".
6. En el "Server Explorer" crea una nueva tabla en la base de datos (en ejemplo: MyDB), agrega algunas tablas y datos.

Y luego prueba algo parecido a este codigo (recuerda siempre llamar a la directiva `using`):

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=MyDB.sdf"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from MyTable where Field2 like '%AB%'";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Field1: {0}", reader[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Debería de funcionar en todas partes con eso, saludos!

Comment: pero la pregunta hace uso de Sql Server no de Sql Compact, es un .mdf no un .sdf lo que esta utilizando. Para que funcione en todas las pcs debes instalar el servicio local o en un servidor centralizado y todos se conecten a este

Comment: Pero su pregunta puede hacer referencia a que escribió algún programa que necesita guardar sus datos en una DB y quiere correrlo en cualquier ordenador que no sea el suyo, ¿No?

Comment: pues la verdad entonces no estaba clara la pregunta, si usa Sql Server no tiene nada que ver con Sql Compact. Si usaba Sql Server tambien podria conectarse sin problemas siempre que tenga el servicio iniciado

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero que debes definir es si la db estara local en la pc del usuario o en un servidor centralizado

Si estara local entonces debes instalar el Sql Server en la pc del usuario, luego en el connection string usarias

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

alli use `.\SQLEXpress` si es que instalas Sql Server Expres, pero tambien puede ser `Server=(localdb)\v11.0;`

Ahora si el servidor estara remoto lo primero que debes validar es si este expone el servicio a la red

[Enable Remote Connection on SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)

tambien valida que el FireWall de windows no este bloqueando la conexion al puerto de Sql Server
El connection string seria

```
Server=ServerIpoNombre;Database=NombreDatabse;Trusted_Connection=True;
```